# Reading Image data from Table's Cell via Apache POI

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I am stuck in one place and I need help immediately,following is the my problem.

Actually I am using Apache POI (XWPF) to read word (.docx) document, I am able to read successfully the table data except the image which is also inside the table's cell. Since I am new to this Api but as per my understanding i think we can read image byte data from cell as well.

```
POIXMLDocumentPart pictureData=(POIXMLDocumentPart)imageCell.getPart();

PackageRelationship packageRelationship=pictureData.getPackageRelationship();

System.out.println("Source URI:"+packageRelationship.getSourceURI());

System.out.println("Target URI:"+packageRelationship.getTargetURI());
```

in above code I can get Image URI as Target but i don't know how to get Image's binary data.

Any Idea friends...

Thanks,
-Javed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from a Table Cell, [get the list of paragraphs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#getParagraphs%28%29). Next, from the [paragraph](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html), get the [list of Runs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#getRuns%28%29). Finally, from the run, [get the list of pictures embedded in the run](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#getEmbeddedPictures%28%29), and you're largely there.

The .docx text extractor in Apache Tika shows how to do all this, see [the source code of it](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/ooxml/XWPFWordExtractorDecorator.java) for details. Generally though, it's something like

```
for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
  for (XWPFRun run : p.getRuns()) {
    for (XWPFPicture pic : run.getEmbeddedPictures()) {
       byte[] pictureData = pic.getPictureData().getData();
    }
  }
}
```

.

There is also a much less common kind of way of embedding pictures into a .docx file, which is much more fiddly to work with. On a XWPFDocument, you can use [getAllPictures()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getAllPictures%28%29) and [getAllPackagePictures()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getAllPackagePictures%28%29) to track down the others, but that won't tell you where in the file the pictures belong.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I tried this approach but I am getting NullPointerException inside pic object, please see the stack trace  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFPicture.getPictureData(XWPFPicture.java:67)
 at com.jawed.test.TestPictures.playWithCell(TestPictures.java:128)
 at com.jawed.test.TestPictures.listTablesFromDocument(TestPictures.java:109)
 at com.jawed.test.TestPictures.main(TestPictures.java:51)

Comment: Make sure you're on the latest version of POI (3.8 final)

Comment: Thanks it worked fine but for those documents(.docx) which i create myself, actually my scenario is I have got documents in .doc format and I am converting those into .docx via microsoft's tool(OFC). so getEmbeddedPictures() method returns 0 pictures but it works fine for self created .docx documents. any idea? or another way to get pictures from paragarph

Comment: Answer updated, you can get those pictures fairly easily, but not where they came from. However, if you have a .doc file to start with, why not just use HWPF to get the pictures from that directly?

Comment: first I had tried HWPF but i found this api unstable, actually the problem is that the pictures(Application Screenshots) are inside the table,which is also containing screen id, so my requirement is to get screen id, which is in first row of the table,and screen shot,which is in last row, and then save screenshot with having  extracted screen id from first row.

Comment: I found another workaround of this issue, I am using autohotkey to convert .doc files into docx via microsoft word 2007 and then extracting tabels' data and images.Thanks for your help.